# Getting "Run-time error '13': Type mismatch"-error when comparing two cells

Tags: vba, error-handling, type-mismatch

The purpose of this macro is to copy data from many input sheets into the sheet "Basis" of a master/main workbook called "Kompensation test5" based on two criteria. The macro should 1) validate if the input sheet is in the same month as the main workbook. If so, 2) it should copy the relevant data for the relevant routes. Currently I'm getting

`Run-time error '13': Type mismatch`

at line 58 (commented with capital letters in the code). What is wrong here?

I've uploaded and example of the main workbook and an example of one of the input workbooks. The date-cell (cell B9) of the input workbooks usually has the month followed by "-" and the year, fx "February - 2016". I'm splitting it on line 58 to make it comparable to the the months in the first row of the "Basis" sheet in the main workbook.

[image]

```
Sub combineall()

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Call lista
    Call CopyLookup

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True

    Workbooks("Kompensation test5").Sheets("List").Delete
    Workbooks("Kompensation test5").Sheets("Basis").Activate

End Sub


Sub CopyLookup()
    Dim Path As String
    Dim Fil As String
    Dim strName As String
    Dim wbk_main As Workbook, wbk_input As Workbook
    Dim ws_main As Worksheet, ws_input As Worksheet
    Dim rng_main As Range, rng_main_date As Range, rng_input As Range, rng_input_date As Range
    Dim c_main As Range, c_main_date As Range, c_input As Range
    i = 2

    While Workbooks("Kompensation test5").Sheets("List").Cells(i, 1) <> ""
    t = Workbooks("Kompensation test5").Sheets("List").Cells(i, 1)

    Set wbk_main = ActiveWorkbook
    Path = "I:\folderpath" & t

    q = 1
     'Start outer loop
    Do While q <> ""

        Set wbk_input = Workbooks.Open(Path)
        Set ws_input = wbk_input.Sheets(1)

        Set rng_main_date = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Basis").Range("1:1")
        Set rng_input_date = ws_input.Range("B9")

        Set rng_input = ws_input.Range("R10:AL10")

        For Each c_main_date In rng_main_date
            If c_main_date.Value <> "" Then
                For Each c_input In rng_input_date
                    If c_input.Value <> "" Then
                        For x = 1 To 100
                        If InStr(Workbooks("Kompensation test5").Sheets("Basis").Cells(1, x), Split(Replace(Workbooks(ws_input).Range(rng_input_date).Value, "-", " "), " ")) > 0 Then 'ERROR HERE!
                            k = x
                        End If
                        Next x
                        Workbooks("Kompensation test5").Sheets("Basis").Range(Cells(4, k - 1), Cells(19, k - 1)).Select
                    End If
                Next c_input
            End If
        Next c_main_date

        Set rng_main = Workbooks("Kompensation test5").Sheets("Basis").Range(Cells(4, k - 1), Cells(19, k - 1))

         'Split cell if containing many values
        ws_input.Range("B10").Select
        Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("R10"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
        :=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), _
        Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1), Array(11, 1), Array(12, 1)), _
        TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

         'Loop through each cell in col I in sheet 2:
        For Each c_main In rng_main
            If c_main.Value <> "" Then
                For Each c_input In rng_input
                    If c_input.Value = c_main.Value Then
                        c_main.Offset(0, 3).Value = wbk_input.Sheets(1).Range("F13").Value
                        q = ""
                         'Move on to next cell in sheet 2:
                        Exit For '(exits the "For Each c_input In rng_input" loop)
                    End If
                Next c_input
            End If
        Next c_main

        rng_input.Delete
        wbk_input.Close False

    Loop

    i = i + 1
    Wend

End Sub

Sub lista()
    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim objFile As Object
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ws = Worksheets.Add
    With ActiveSheet
    .Name = "List"
    End With

    fldrpath = "I:\folderpath"
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(fldrpath)
    ws.Cells(1, 1).Value = "The files found in " & objFolder.Name & "are:"

    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        ws.Cells(ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1, 1).Value = objFile.Name
    Next

    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set objFile = Nothing
    Set objFSO = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to refer to the Worksheet in the Workbook

```
Workbooks(ws_input).Range(rng_input_date).Value
```

Should be

```
Workbooks(ws_input).Sheets("SHEETNAME").Range(rng_input_date).Value
```

And just to make sure:

```
Workbooks("Kompensation test5").Sheets("Basis").Cells(1, x).Value
```

Instead of

```
Workbooks("Kompensation test5").Sheets("Basis").Cells(1, x)
```

And if that still doesn't work, it's because you are comparing a value of a range to a value of a cell, so change

```
Workbooks(ws_input).Sheets("SHEETNAME").Range(rng_input_date).Value
```

To

```
Workbooks(ws_input).Sheets("SHEETNAME").Cells(9,2).Value 'If your Date is in Cell B9
```

Comment: Makes sense :) Tried both approaches. Both produced the same error as before (at the same line).

Comment: Then seperate every step of the error line into one line and try to find out where the error occurs

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `.Value` after the `Cells(1, x)`

Also see the following:

When refering directly to the `WorkBook` Name you need to include the extension. So you need to add the extension for the file "Kompensation test5" to make it "Kompensation test5.xls" or whatever the extension is.

When you wanting a value from a `Range` and you have set the `Range` already, you only need to use the `Range` name and the `.Value` so for for the second line you just need `rng_input_date.Value`

So line 58 should be something like this, assuming that the "Kompensation test5" file extension is .xls

```
 If InStr(Workbooks("Kompensation test5.xlsm").Sheets("Basis").Cells(1, x).Value, Workbooks(ws_input).Range(rng_input_date).Value) > 0 Then 'ERROR HERE!
     k = x
 End If
```

But remember that the `Split` function creates an `Array` so there will then be a type mismatch.

You not really comparing the data in "Kompensation test5" and "Mappe1" properly. Please check the raw data and let us know the data for the cells being compared, is the data just a word or 2015/02/19 of which only the month is being displayed.

Your `For Loop` also will not work properly because your Month names in the "Kompensation test5" sheet is only in every 7th Column, so you need to use

`For x = 1 To 100 Step 7`

This will then select the cells in which the Month display is inserted when using a merged cell range.

Comment: Tried adding .value, but I got the same error at the same line.

Comment: @Saud have a look now, there is still alot in that line which is not correct. 
So please provide the following:

>The actual raw data in cells B9 of Mappe1   
>The actual raw data in Row 1 (Month Values) "Kompensation test5"   This will help with getting the month comparison correct.

Comment: I've added the extension, referred to the range properly and taken into account that the month in the main workbook is in every 7th column. The data in cell B9 of the input workbooks is a word/string. An example would be "January - 2016", which has to be compared to "January" in the main workbook. That's why I'm using the split function. The name of the month is always followed by a year.

Comment: @Saud is it working? If not, where is it not working?

Comment: I now get the "Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range" error at the same line as before. I guess the error occurs because I do not specify the number of elements in the array.

Comment: @Saud you also refering to "Kompensation test5" and your `WorkBook` is called "Kompensation test"

Comment: Thought my extension was .xls, but it's .xlsm. Have corrected it now. The name of the current workbook that I'm working in right now is actually called "Kompensation test5" :) . Sry for the misleading screenshot. I now get the following error: "Run-time error '13': Type mismatch" (which was the original error).

Comment: @Saud have a look at my answer now, the If statment. You dont need the whole Split replace part

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106688/discussion-between-saud-and-jean-pierre-oosthuizen).